# Is it possible to resolve and view the result of a promise while debugging a test in Protactor?

Tags: javascript, protractor, cucumberjs, chai-as-promised

I am trying to debug a test in a CucumberJS/Protractor/Chai-as-promised stack.

```
var tableDataRows = $('.example-table-under-test').$$('tr');
var dataToTest = tableDataRows.map(function(rows, index) {
  if (index > 0) {
    var cells = rows.$$('td');
    return {
      'ATTRIBUTE A': cells.first().getText(),
      'ATTRIBUTE B': cells.get(1).getText(),
      'ATTRIBUTE C': cells.get(2).getText(),
      'ATTRIBUTE D': cells.get(3).getText(),
      'ATTRIBUTE E': cells.get(4).getText(),
      'ATTRIBUTE F': cells.get(5).getText()
    };
  }
});
return chai.expect(dataToTest).to.eventually.deeply.equal(tableSpec.hashes());
```

When I ran the test, I got the following error message despite the cucumber specs matching up with the table values on the screen:

`AssertionError: expected [ Array(8) ] to deeply equal [ Array(7) ]`

I figured since the mapper was ignoring the first row of `th` elements, 7 should equal 7, so I wanted to debug the test. At first I tried just adding `then` to the `map` like `tableDataRows.map(...).then(console.error)` (since `.map` off a protractor `element.all` / [$$](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.$$) [returns a promise](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.map)) to output the data mapped from the `tableDataRows`, but that didn't result in any data.

I tried `then`ing a random function that didn't even use the resolved output to just see if it was executing, and that it didn't - so I figure that just a `then` isn't resolving the promise.

```
.then(function() {
  console.error("I executed");
  // this didn't work either
});
```

After that, I tried putting a log line in the map function just above the return since that seemed to be resolving, and that worked - 7 times (which is what I'd expect for the mapper skipping the header row, but it's confusing because the test claims there's 8 elements in the array. Anyway..)

So somehow the `.to.eventually` in `chai-as-promised` is resolving promises (like the documentation said it would), but I don't see how my `.then()` after the `.map()` function isn't resolving anything, or how any of my other attempts weren't resolving the promise either.

Is it possible to resolve the promise without returning the `chai.expect` (presumed) promise that wraps the promise used to get data for the expect? -- I also noticed nothing would resolve if I just had `chai.expect(...).to.eventually.equal(...)` without a preceding return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A coworker ended up pointing me in the right direction on this. One of my early attempts was the answer - adding `.then` to the `.map` chain, but when I was testing that I wasn't returning the `chai.expect()` of all that. By putting it there and returning it, the promises all got resolved and I got the output I was looking for.

```
var tableDataRows = $('.example-table-under-test').$$('tr');
var dataToTest = tableDataRows.map(function(rows, index) {
  if (index > 0) {
    var cells = rows.$$('td');
    return {
      'ATTRIBUTE A': cells.first().getText(),
      'ATTRIBUTE B': cells.get(1).getText(),
      'ATTRIBUTE C': cells.get(2).getText(),
      'ATTRIBUTE D': cells.get(3).getText(),
      'ATTRIBUTE E': cells.get(4).getText(),
      'ATTRIBUTE F': cells.get(5).getText()
    };
  }
}).then(function(resolvedMap) {
  console.error(resolvedMap);
});
return chai.expect(dataToTest).to.eventually.deeply.equal(tableSpec.hashes());
```